# How can I make the content of a Label change after one second using JavaFX?

Tags: java, multithreading, loops, javafx, sleep

I'm trying make a Splash Screen, so I need that some words stays appearing. I used o Thread, but I don't know how can I make a loop for label appear and after one second it changes.

```
package br.com.codeking.zarsystem.splash;

import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.concurrent.WorkerStateEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class ControllerSplash {

    @FXML
    Label lblLoading;



    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        System.out.println("app start");

        lblLoading.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 16px;" + "-fx-font-family: Ubuntu;"
                + " -fx-text-fill: white;");
```

here I've tried to repeat this step 10 times, but it don't works

```
        while (i <= 10) {

            Task<Void> sleeper = new Task<Void>() {

                @Override
                protected Void call() throws Exception {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1500);

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    return null;
                }
            };

            sleeper.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(WorkerStateEvent event) {

                    lblLoading.setText("to change " + i);
                }
            });
             new Thread(sleeper).run();

                i++;
        }
    }

}
```

I can't execute this in a for loop? So I don't have idea what I
 have to do... I'm looking for, but nothing helps me. Can you? Thank
very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `PauseTransition`:

```
 PauseTransition pauseTransition = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(1));
 pauseTransition.setOnFinished(e -> lblLoading.setText("complete"));
 pauseTransition.play();
```